# When is $1-(1-p)^n \sim pn$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, approximation

Let $0<p=p(n)<1$ with $p=o(1)$. For which $p$ is it true that $1-(1-p)^n \sim pn$?

With $\sim$ I mean that they are asymptotically the same, so $\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{pn}\rightarrow 1$, or at least that $\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{pn}\rightarrow c$ for some constant $c$.

Which kind of series expansion do I need for that?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: What do you mean by writing $p(n)$? Does $p$ vary with $n$ or not?

Comment: With that I mean that $p$ varies with $n$, so $p$ depends on $n$, for example $p=\frac{\log(n)}{n}$, say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before his edit**

Pretty sure it only works for functions $p(n)=o(1)$ (using little-$o$ notation).  Otherwise, $p(n)=\Omega(1)$, so $1-(1-p(n))^n=\Omega(p(n)^n)$.  Assuming $p \rightarrow \infty$, we know $\frac{p(n)^n}{np(n)} \rightarrow \infty$.

**After his edit**

I found that for my ratio, $p(n) \sim n^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$ yields $p^n \sim np$.  However, it's possible $1-(1-p)^n \neq O(p^n)$.  It's fairly easy to see that $1-(1-p)^n \sim (1+p)^n= O(\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}p^n)$, and $(1+p)^n=\Omega(p^n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I wasn't precise enough, because I actually am only interested in $p$s such that $p=o(1)$, so your answer totally makes sense to me but doesn't really help me in the end to solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll add whatever else I can think of.